# Can I hide angular build progress output when running tests from karma?

Tags: angular, karma-runner

I am configuring a build process for an Angular 4 application and would like to silence progress output as it muddies the runner's logs.

The project configs were generated using angular cli (v1.0.1)

Using `ng build`, it is possible to pass a `--no-progress` flag to silence the build/compilation progress output.

Is it possible to configure karma in a way to silence progress output for the build it performs before tests are run?

Comment: How do you run tests? I think there should be an `ng build` command somewhere in the way you run tests that you can add your `--no-progress` flag

Comment: @eddyP23 I was running tests with:
`karma start --single-run --reporters teamcity`

Comment: Per Mezo below, switched to: `ng test --watch=false --progress=false --reporters=teamcity` and things work as expected

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the `--progress` flag. It works for `ng build` and `ng serve` as well.

`ng test --progress=false`